# How to tell if a file can be renamed before using os.rename

Tags: python, operating-system, file-rename

I would like to determine if a file can be renamed before calling `os.rename`. I tried using `os.access(path, os.W_OK)` but it returns `True` even when the file cannot be renamed. I am guessing that write access is different than rename access.

My program takes in a list of drawing file names. The drawing names have their sheet numbers encoded in an inconvenient format. The program extracts the drawing number and sheet number (from the file name) and then appends "Sheet 1 of 3", "Sheet 2 of 3" etc as appropriate for the drawings. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) say its best to use EAFP but I would like to be able to not rename *any* files from a sheet group even if only *one* cannot be renamed. Using EAFP I might rename a drawing and then later find out one of its companion drawings cannot be renamed.

The only solution I've imagined thus far is to rename all of the files to their same name i.e. `os.rename(oldName, oldName)`, storing which ones failed, and then only applying the new names to drawing sets that did not cause errors. That would work but that seemed like a pretty big hack.

Any suggestions?

```
badfilenames = ['00_3214.dwg', '01_3214.dwg', '02_3214.dwg',
                '00_7321.dwg', '02_7321.dwg',
                '00_8821.dwg',
                ]

generatedfilenames = ['3214 Sheet 1 of 3.dwg', '3214 Sheet 2 of 3.dwg', '3214 Sheet 2 of 3.dwg',
                      '7321 Sheet 1 of 2.dwg', '7321 Sheet 2 of 2.dwg',
                      '8821 Sheet 1 of 1.dwg',
                      ]
```

Comment: It's better not to do this. It's better to just attempt a rename, and if it fails, do something reasonable. The reason is that even if you do a check, that check is racy--something may delete the file, or change permissions, between the time you check, and the time you do the rename. Depending on your application, the chances of this may be high or low, but it's always a risk. It's better to be defensive :)

Comment: This sounds like an OS-specific question to me.  On some systems, you need to have write permission on the parent directory (aka the parent folder).  Some may require write access to the file.  And on other systems there may be more specific permissions that specifically allow or disallow renaming of a file.

Comment: I think it would be best to iteratively rename the files and "undo" any that previously succeeded if you encounter one that doesn't. As far as I know there's no way to test renaming a file short of attempting to do it (unless there's some pattern to ones that are failing).